# How can I edit a partition on a drive to be a boot partition?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

I have recently installed an SSD into my PC which I want to move my main OS and programs over to. I want to be able to boot from this SSD. I have used a program called EaseUS to clone my old HDD onto the new SSD but I cannot boot from it as the partition on the SSD is not a boot partition.

Is there any way I can turn this partition into a boot partition or maybe create a new partition as a boot partition? I have no problems with re-cloning my drive afterwards if needs be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably only cloned the C partition and not the hidden 100MB boot partition. The easiest would be to copy the bootmgr to C and then clone the C partition again. Here is my tutorial on how to copy the bootmgr to C.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/209885-bootmgr-move-c-easybcd.html

Comment: I did this and I now get another error. https://gyazo.com/a9927c8d13104f613f71d31b799c801f Sorry for the poor image :/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: David, do you have any more "intelligent" requests